# how to set django setting path in docker container app?

Tags: python, django, docker, django-channels

i'm inside docker container. and getting following error:

```
File "./source/asgi.py", line 14, in <module>
    from notifications.sockets import routing
  File "./notifications/sockets/routing.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import consumers
  File "./notifications/sockets/consumers.py", line 7, in <module>
    from projects.models import Project
  File "./projects/models.py", line 6, in <module>
    User = get_user_model()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 160, in get_user_model
    return django_apps.get_model(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, require_ready=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting AUTH_USER_MODEL, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

where my asgi file code is here below:

```
import os
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from notifications.sockets import routing

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'source.settings')

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
  "http": get_asgi_application(),
  "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            routing.websocket_urlpatterns,
        )
    ),
})
```

i don't get it whats wrong here.. please help me out in solving this issue... thank you.

Answer (score 0):

answering here bc I can't comment yet but can you provide us the `MIDDLEWARE` array in your *settings.py* file and your *Dockerfile* ?

This is where the error seems to be. You may have missed to include `AuthMiddleware` or another needed middleware, either in *settings.py* or in your virtualenv variables, or Docker does not load these variables properly.